# Doubled, Tripled negative counterparts

Tags: mathematics

We can say "The company earnings has doubled/tripled over the period".

My question is - are there negative counterparts for doubled/tripled for the cases when some value lost 50% or 66% of its initial number?

Comment: I can only think or sth that is *halved*. For others I would use *decrease* by e.g. one third. But I'm not a native :-)

Comment: @bobbee - If earnings were 3M last year and 1.5M this year, then, yes, the earnings have halved. If they were 3M last year and 2M this year, then they decreased by one-thirds. That all said, if losses were 2M last year and 4M this year, then losses were doubled – even though that's in the negative direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Halved** is the only word in regular use when talking about reductions, beyond this we would tend to give a more wordy explanation. "Quartered" could *just about* work as it does mean "split into 4", but would sound very strange even to a native speaker and should be avoided.

A native would usually structure the sentence using one of the following formats

> The company earnings reduced by 40% over the period
>
> *(ie they are now 60% of the original, having lost 40%)*

Or

> The company earnings dropped to 40% of the previous year
>
> *(ie they are now 40% of the original, having lost 60%)*

We may use percentages or fractions in these sentences, eg the earnings may drop by 20%, or by 1/5. They may drop to 25%, or to 1/4. Note that this is always given with reference to the original amount.

You will almost certainly see, at some stage, some confusion at some stage between reducing **by** and reducing **to** - a combination of a lack of understanding of language and/or mathematics. This is fairly common when the media report on statistics...

Comment: Originally, decimated meant _reduced to 10% of the starting amount,_ but now it is used to mean _wiped out._

Comment: Indeed, that's why I didn't mention it - the original (Roman/Latin) meaning was a literal 1/10th, but the way it's used now is much more generalised and no longer accurate enough to use without explaining that you are using it precisely: which pretty much negates any need to use it.

Comment: What an amazing, violent world ancient Rome must have been, where the fighting forces suffered losses of exactly 90% so often they had to make up a word for it.

Comment: haha, I believe it was actually the other way around and was used as an extreme punishment: if a large group of soldiers committed a serious crime (eg mutiny), rather than kill them all and lose a major part of your force, the unit would be "Decimated" - ie 1/10th of the force would be killed as a punishment and the rest spread between other units. The idea being that a 1/10th chance of dying would put the survivors off doing it again.

Comment: Ahhh..  That makes sense.  That clears up a perplexment I have had since childhood....And wait - that means decimation only results in 10% losses.  That's not so bad after all.

Comment: Remind me never to join your army....